# How to use Google Custom Search to get large images?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search, google-search-api, google-image-search

This is what I got now, but I still get small images:

```
var customSearchImage;
google.load('search', '1');
google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    var customSearchOptions = {
        enableImageSearch: true,
        disableWebSearch: true,
        imageSearchResultSetSize: "large"
    };
    customSearchImage = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('googleID', customSearchOptions);
    customSearchImage.draw('searchimage'); // set the results div id
}, true);
```

What should I do to get large images (i.e. 400x400) from Google Search?

Comment: You could try to use the REST implementation. Looks like image size is supported there: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

Comment: I've tried that, but this what I got "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup".Where can I signup for it?